# Example of FullCalendar using a private Google Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there an example anywhere of using FullCalendar with a private (but shared) Google Calendar? OUr users are on our site and can be logged in with Google. Using FullCalendar they should be able to see any of our calendars that they're entitled to see. At the moment I can't find an example of how to use FullCalendar on a private Google Calendar.

Right now - if I'm signed in - I get this. You can see the normal embedded Google calendar above, and the FullCalendar result below. [Google embed vs FullCalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbpnB.png)

The code is basically the code from the FullCalendar example page.

Comment: You might have to fetch the events via the Google API instead and plug into fullCalendar using the events-as-a-function feature

Comment: And how might I do that?

Comment: Well I've just outlined the process. Is there something within that which is puzzling you? Have you used Google APIs before? It's very well documented and there are ready-made client libraries available in many languages including JavaScript. As for the fullCalendar part, again it's well documented... https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function, https://developers.google.com/calendar/api

Comment: How to actually do it is what's puzzling me. Yes, I've used Google APIs before. The Google APIs aren't the problem. The FullCalendar part isn't well documented, which is why I'm asking if there's an example anywhere.

Comment: Well there's an example of the concept in the fullCalendar documentation I linked you to. Just replace the sample Ajax call in there with a call to the Google API (you can use their JavaScript client library to make it easier) to get events from the relevant calendar. Get the response from Google, transform the data into fullCalendar's event format and return it via the provided callback

Comment: Which is why I was asking if there was an example anywhere.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of personally. No doubt there some examples of using the calendar API in Google's documentation. So try and plug that together with the fullCalendar example, as I described. Are you stuck / confused about any specific aspect of what to do? Maybe give it a try and post your attempt here if you get stuck.

Comment: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2642